# The ring homomorphism between a commutative ring $R$ and its localization $S^{-1}R$ is invertible on $S$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and $S$ be a multiplicative subset, let $S^{-1}R$ be the localization, and defines a ring homomorphism $l: R\to S^{-1}R$ such that $l(a)=\frac{a}{1}$. Can someone tell me or give me some hints on why $l(s)$ is invertible for every $s\in S$?
Thank you!

Comment: If $l(s) = s/1$, what would you naively think of as an inverse? Is that element in the localization?

Comment: Oh... I see, I think I misunderstand the word "invertible", so here invertible means the inverse element of $l(s)$ in $S^{-1}R$, not mean that the function $l$ is injective on $S$?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: While this is not the point of the question, it is worth noting that indeed the map $s\mapsto s/1$ need not be injective. We may have $S^{-1}R=0$. Another situation is the following: $R=k[x,y]/(x^2,xy)$, and localize with respect to the prime ideal $\mathfrak p=xR$. Then, $y/1=(y+x)/1$ in $R_{\mathfrak p}$.